# UnicodeDecodeError: ('utf-8' codec) while reading a dta file in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, stata

I am trying to open a `dta` file with Pandas but get a `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_stata('/some/stata/file.dta',encoding='utf8') # I've tried 'utf8', "ISO-8859-1", 'latin1', 'cp1252' and not putting in anything, same error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#123>", line 1, in <interactive>
    pd.read_stata(path,encoding='cp1252')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/stata.py", line 161, in read_stata
    chunksize=chunksize, encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/stata.py", line 960, in __init__
    self._read_header()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/stata.py", line 980, in _read_header
    self._read_new_header(first_char)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/stata.py", line 1056, in _read_new_header
    self.vlblist = self._get_vlblist()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/stata.py", line 1127, in _get_vlblist
    for i in range(self.nvar)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/stata.py", line 1269, in _decode
    return s.decode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 18: invalid start byte
```

The file contains non-ASCII characters and was saved (probably on a Windows or Mac) by someone else. **R** can open the file and save it as a `csv`, which I can then read normally, but it would be nice to be able to do everything with Python.

For the encoding argument, following other threads here, I have tried 'utf8', "ISO-8859-1", 'latin1', 'cp1252' and not putting in anything. However, I always get the exact same error.

Any idea what is going on and what can I do?

I'm using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 in case that matters.

Comment: 'utf', 'utf-8', 'iso-8859-1' work. 'utf8' doesn't. Using either Python 2.7 or 3.5, withPandas 0.19.1. Can you check your pandas version (`pd.__version__`)

Comment: @JulienMarrec just updated pandas from 0.18.1 to 0.20.3 - same error persists. Looks like there's a reported [solved bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4626) on this from 4 years ago, but still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

A fix was committed to master on Github and should be released with version `0.25`.

See details about this issue [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25960).

For a temporary fix, change line `1334` of `pandas.io.stata` from

```
return s.decode('utf-8')
```

to

```
return s.decode('latin-1')
```

Unfortunately, there are certain cases where Stata, or perhaps other software, will allow some non-`UTF-8` characters in. Presumably, you are using a `dta` file the version of which is `118` and since these are supposed to be pure `UTF-8`, Pandas ignores the encoding `kwarg`.